# VBox Guest Addition 6.1.32 install fails on Ubuntu 20.04.4 in Win7 Ult 64 bit

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-7, 64-bit

I have a 64 bit Win7 Ultimate guest VM installed on 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS box. Install of the Guest Additions for 6.1.32 VBox fails with "ERROR (800b0100) No signature was present in the subject".

A msg at the top of the install dialog says "Installation Aborted. Setup was not completed successfully."

Any suggested fixes/work arounds? The VM is completely useless without access to the host file system. The postage stamp display is no panacea either.

Comment: Do you think the error is on the Ubuntu side?  This sounds like a Windows error that would need a Windows solution. Why did you tag 12.04?

Comment: I do suspect the problem is Ububtu related. Been running a VM created from the same .iso on a Win10 host since mid 2019. Have applied numerous VBox & VBox Guest updates and have not had any problems. On Ubuntu the VM is dead in the water immediately

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not support SHA2-based driver signatures out of the box, so you first must install the following windows 7 update:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sha-2-code-signing-support-update-for-windows-server-2008-r2-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-september-23-2019-84a8aad5-d8d9-2d5c-6d78-34f9aa5f8339

After installation and a reboot the mouse driver can be installed without problems.

You can make the file available to the Windows inside VirtualBox with devices > optical drive > create image.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is generally caused when Windows Defender doesn’t like something in the `.msi` that is being installed. There are three possible solutions to this issue:

1. Disable Windows Defender (and any other anti-virus mechanism that might be running), then try the installation again
2. View the Guest Addition files with Explorer, then run the installation `.exe` manually (e.g.: `VboxWindowsAdditions-x86.exe`)
3. Install an older version of the Guest Additions. I have found [the 6.1.0 ISO](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.0/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.0.iso) to be the most reliable on older Windows clients such as Vista and Win2K. The guest additions version does not need to match the version of VirtualBox, though it is usually better when they do.

Hopefully one of these will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly these are all things I've tried to no joy. I had hoped this issue may be something caused by a known Ubuntu wrinkle. I suspect Ubuntu because a VM created from the same .iso has been running perfectly on a Win10host over many VBox upgrades since mid-2019. Have no interest in perusing the issue. What I was doing was a proof of concept test to determine if migrating to Ubunu as my host OS is viable. The VM dead in the water just outside the gate is a resounding NOT!